# Emoji not showing in Swift

Tags: ios, emoji, swift4, iphone7plus

I am trying to show emojis coming from JSON response. It work fine when we don't have 0️⃣1️⃣3️⃣5️⃣ in below string and does not work with below string.

```
var titleLabelString = \ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude18\u2626\ufe0f 0️⃣1️⃣3️⃣5️⃣
```

Function I am using:

```
extension String {
    var decodeEmoji: String? {
      let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false);
      let decodedStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue)
      if decodedStr != nil{
        return decodedStr as String?
    }
      return self
}
}
```

Using it like:

```
titleLabelString = titleLabelString.decodeEmoji!
```

What is wrong in this?

Comment: are you using system font, or some custom one?

Comment: Your first line of code is not valid as Swift, so it is not clear what you are suffering for. Can you show us the actual contents of the original string? `print(titleLabelString.unicodeScalars.map{uc in String(format:"U+%04X", uc.value)}.joined(separator: " "))`

Comment: @OOPer: The actual string is " \ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude18\u2626\ufe0f 0️⃣1️⃣3️⃣5️⃣ " , it prints the string as it is with out converting the encoded emojis.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ: I am using Font-Awesome font family.

Comment: `" \ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude18\u2626\ufe0f 0️⃣1️⃣3️⃣5️⃣ "` is not a valid String literal in Swift. Please show exact output generated with my code above.

Comment: @OOPer: Below Is the output:
U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0038 U+0033 U+0064 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0065 U+0030 U+0061 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0038 U+0033 U+0064 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0065 U+0031 U+0038 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0038 U+0033 U+0064 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0065 U+0030 U+0032 U+0035 U+FE0F U+20E3 U+0033 U+FE0F U+20E3 U+0031 U+FE0F U+20E3 U+0030 U+FE0F U+20E3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code points you have shown in the comment:

```
U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0038 U+0033 U+0064 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0065 U+0030 U+0061 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0038 U+0033 U+0064 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0065 U+0031 U+0038 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0038 U+0033 U+0064 U+005C U+0075 U+0064 U+0065 U+0030 U+0032 U+0035 U+FE0F U+20E3 U+0033 U+FE0F U+20E3 U+0031 U+FE0F U+20E3 U+0030 U+FE0F U+20E3
```

represents a string like this:

#### \ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude025️⃣3️⃣1️⃣0️⃣

(Seems you have chosen another string than in your question.)

As a valid String literal in Swift, it becomes:

```
"\\ud83d\\ude0a\\ud83d\\ude18\\ud83d\\ude02\u{0035}\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}\u{0033}\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}\u{0031}\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}\u{0030}\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}"
```

Anyway, you have a string where non-BMP characters are represented with JSON-string like escaped sequence. And your `decodeEmoji` cannot convert them into valid characters.

You can forcefully convert such strings:

```
extension String {
    var jsonStringRedecoded: String? {
        let data = ("\""+self+"\"").data(using: .utf8)!
        let result = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! String
        return result
    }
}
```

(If your string may contain some more meta-characters, you may need to modify this code.)

```
var titleLabelString = "\\ud83d\\ude0a\\ud83d\\ude18\\ud83d\\ude02\u{0035}\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}\u{0033}\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}\u{0031}\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}\u{0030}\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}"

print(titleLabelString.jsonStringRedecoded) //->5️⃣3️⃣1️⃣0️⃣
```

---

But generally, usual JSON decoder can decode non-BMP characters (including emojis). So, if you get this sort of string *from JSON response*,

- Your server may be sending invalid JSON response

or

- You may be using a broken JSON decoder

You should better check these things before using forced re-decoding.

Comment: I'm having an emoji from the server as "U+1F44D" but that is not being displayed using the above solution. Could you please suggest any other solution?
Thanks!

Comment: @RajatMishra, you should better start a new thread of your own. You may need to show more details to get suggestions.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!