# Converting emoji from JSON string to character

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, emoji

I am trying to convert the emoji encoding string to character from JSON string.Some emoji are converting and some are not.

Function I am using:

```
extension String {
var decodeEmoji: String? {
    let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let decodedStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue)
    if decodedStr != nil {
        return decodedStr as String?
    }
    return self
    }
}


JSON string: Altre novitÃ  in arrivo oggi...  \ud83d\udcaa\ud83c\udffb
```

"`\ud83d\udcaa\ud83c\udffb`" is the emoji string of  character.

Comment: All JSON decoders (JSONDecoder, JSONSerialization) handle that automatically ....

Comment: `String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue` — Why ASCII?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977889/7104617) or for displaying emotions you can use `NSAttributedString`

```
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

For example, create an extension for `UILabel`

```
@implementation UILabel (Emotion)

- (void)setHtmlText:(NSString *)text
{
    self.text = text;

    NSDictionary *attributes = [self.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 longestEffectiveRange:nil inRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.attributedText.length)];

    NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

    [attrStr addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)];

    self.attributedText = attrStr;
}

@end
```

Comment: @Vinodh, Swift version that was edited in doesn't look like Objective C version **at all**. If you wanted to show your idea you should've post it in your own answer.

Comment: It's not my idea. it was mentioned in the answer what @Alexey Kudlay has mentioned. Please read then start to scold me

Comment: @Vinodh, Yes, he mentioned other answer as a link, but your edit marks **two completely different** code snippets as **ObjC** and **Swift** versions of answer. They are not versions, they are two different solutions! And can be both represented in Objective C and Swift.

Comment: Please revert back the original answer

Comment: @Vinodh, well, i've tried, but it wasn't peer approwed.

Comment: it's not my fault